# Realtime HTTP API Gateway with DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I think I made a mistake in my planning at some point and chose HTTP API Gateway + DynamoDB thinking I could implement a real time app (for example the way a cross-platform todo list works). I didn't choose AWS Amplify because it lacks support for macOS computers and it's only good for mobile and web. So now that I spent so much time getting familiar with the stack at the beginning above:

Is there a way to implement real-time using http api and dynamo for cross-platform operations?

Comment: I don't believe there is a direct integration with Http Api and DyanmoDb without a lambda in between. is it too late to use REST api ?

Comment: Kind of late yes, I'm using Lambda in between, how would you suggest with lambda? @BaluVyamajala

Comment: Regular [Http Api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-routes.html) calling Lambda functions which talk to Dynamo? are you running into any issues?

Comment: No, no issues. I can do regular CRUD requests defined in the lambda using the http gateway with proxy integration. The puzzle is having that data to work in realtime in my macOS and iOS app, what do I use for that?

Comment: I misunderstood. we probably need to use (websocket Api([https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api.html} and it not http/rest , it is a separate category :(